# Is it necessary to run "ROLLBACK" in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I executed multiple queries SQL statement in between `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`.

If anything goes wrong, the process terminated in between without executing `COMMIT` and nothing will happen to the database. So far, everything seems fine without executing `ROLLBACK`.

My doubt is, is it necessary to run `ROLLBACK` if anything bad happens?

Comment: *If anything goes wrong, the process terminated* This is absolutely incorrect. Never rely on implicit actions. Define proper exit handler(s) and perform explicit ROLLBACK in it.

Comment: @Akina That is so true. Each framework/solution can behave a bit different under error conditions, and I've seen transactions been committed even after some errors were supposed to doom the transaction. So, to the point, it's better to call ROLLBACK explicitly and sleep well at night.

Comment: @TheImpaler It's enough to imagine that in the middle of transaction the link was lost, and then restored by reconnection - but this is another connection... good bye, consistency!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `autocommit` disabled, any non-commited transaction is always rolled back at the end of the session.

You can read more about it [on the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html)

That said, I'd be explicit about it (just in case the session doesn't end when "something goes wrong") and call it.

Comment: I found 1 useful info about `rollback` in the documentation, which is "Both COMMIT and ROLLBACK release all InnoDB locks that were set during the current transaction". which I interpret that as unless there occurs an InnoDB locks, or else, running `ROLLBACK` is not necessary. Thanks for you info anyway.

Comment: @mjb well, MyISAM doesn't really support transactions, so yes, a rollback is not necessary on MyISAM... but neither is a commit, or a transaction, at all